# Can't set environment variables in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I read a few answers about this. First attempt I did was by going to control panel and editing the environment variables there. However, when I move to powershell and do something like `echo %MPJ_HOME%`. It spits out `%MPJ_HOME%`

I tried restarting the terminal including the PC but it still does not work.

Then I tried running the PowerShell as Administrator and using:

`setx MPJ_HOME "C:\mpj-v0_44" \M`

It says `SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.`.

However, again if I type `echo %MPJ_HOME%` again it prints `%MPJ_HOME%`.

I tried `refreshenv` as well and it still same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

#### I type `echo %MPJ_HOME%` again it prints `%MPJ_HOME%`

PowerShell handles environment variables differently to `cmd`.

To display their values in PowerShell use the following syntax:

```
$Env:variablename
```

Example:

```
> echo %Path%
%Path%
> $Env:Path
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\apps\WSCC\Sysinternals Suite;C:\apps\WSCC\NirSoft Utilities
>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [PowerShell commands - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/)
- [Windows Environment variables - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-env.html)
- [Take Charge of Environment Variables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/take-charge-environment-variables-powershell)